# How to pick MMYYYY from DDMMYYYY IN SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which I have a column `cdate = 17022019`.

Now I want to fetch only `022019` from that `cdate`.

Comment: Is that a string?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT RIGHT(cast(cdate as varchar(10)), 6)
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `17022019` is actually *text*, then you may use the `RIGHT` function:

```
SELECT RIGHT('17022019', 6) AS MY
FROM yourTable;
```

If the column is really a date, which it should be, then we can try using `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(date_col, 'MMyyyy') AS MY
FROM yourTable;
```